# Django: "TypeError: [] is not JSON serializable" Why?

Tags: python, django, json

How can this be that this error was raised? I entered this:

```
def json(self):
    return json.dumps(
        {
            'items': self.items
        }
    )
```

and got that error (because self.items was an empty queryset (Django)

but then,

```
def json(self):
    return json.dumps(
        {
            'items': []  # Pass in empty list to prove that the error was idiotic.
        }
    )
```

worked fine (which at least proves that the error message is worthless)

Is this because the queryset defines **repr**() and returns '[]' as a string when it's empty or something  ridiculous like that?

Comment: Why are you defining a function with the same name as a module you are using?

Comment: @gnibbler It's not a function. It's a method and I'm using it as a @property (didn't include that in my example).

Comment: I love looking back at how smug I was, `...the error was idiotic.`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Querysets are not serializable out-of-the-box. If you try `list(self.items)` instead of just `self.items`, that should work as long as the items themselves are JSON-serializable.

**Update:** It will raise an exception even if it isn't empty. I don't think it'll be accepted as a Django bug, though of course you can try; the simplest answer is to force evaluation using `list(qs)`, as I've already said.

Comment: +1. This is the answer. You are using list(queryset) to force the queryset to be evaluated right away. The underlying data, in the form of a list, is serializable; the queryset itself is not. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id1

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. BTW, This seems like a bug. I'm going to start a ticket for it. Django's serializers are meant for serializing Django querysets. If it raises an exception when it's empty, that's a bug.

Comment: @orokusaki, this doesn't feel like a bug to me. Sometimes you want objects. Sometimes you want strings. Django lets you chose. Here's a more pythonic alternative that works for me, for all Django fields: `[str(obj) for obj in Model.objects.values()]` [see below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14653384/623735)

Answer (score 6):

This is very frustrating.  Django's serialization complains about everything that isn't a query set and json.dumps complains about objects from Django's ORM support.

```
>>> from cluster.models import Account
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(Account.objects.all()[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Account: 9de5-2653-000d-81a3 => foo@bar.net> is not JSON serializable
```

Versus

```
>>> serializers.serialize("json", [clusters])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 91, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 41, in serialize
    for field in obj._meta.local_fields:
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 4):

As Vinay pointed out, even if you cast to a list, serialization often still fails. For me, serialization fails on DateTimeField elements (`datetime.datetime` objects), even if I ask for a `ValuesQuerySet` (list-like) with `.values()`. The solution for me was a simple comprehension.

```
json.dumps([str(obj) for obj in Model.objects.values()]);
```

In your case, that would be

```
return json.dumps({k: str(v) for k, v in self.__dict__.items()})
```

The magic of `str` saves the day. The `repr` built-in may also be helpful if you need object type information in your serialization.